# TinyMCE not showing up in Django admin

Tags: django, tinymce, wysiwyg

I was just trying out tinymce. It worked well with the default config (I didn't put anything in the config). Later I found a few configs on the web and copy pasted them into the settings, and it worked fine. However upon copy pasting another config, the TinyMCE form doesn't seem to be displaying. 
My web app is a blog post.

My settings.py

```
    import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'sid&6o(*h*r!9p+gs-++chd+c(8(awc^u6*1yia5s8a^csmgip'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts',
    'marketing',
    'tinymce',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bootstrapblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join('templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bootstrapblog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')


# Tiny MCE

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height':
    360,
    'width':
    970,
    'cleanup_on_startup':
    True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels':
    20,
    'selector':
    'textarea',
    'theme':
    'modern',
    'plugins':
    '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1':
    '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2':
    '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu':
    'formats | link image',
    'menubar':
    True,
    'statusbar':
    True,
}
```

My model for the blog(only relevant parts):

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = HTMLField()
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
```

The form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from tinymce import TinyMCE


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=TinyMCE(attrs={
            'required': False,
            'cols': 30,
            'rows': 10
        }))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

All of these were working, till I used the above config. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),` or `path('tynymce/', include('tinymce.urls'))` to your project `urls.py` according to http://romanvm.github.io/django-tinymce4-lite/installation.html

Comment: The problem then in your settings.py `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG`, see here if your config fits requirements [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/general-configuration-guide/basic-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

For the others: There's a big chances, not being able if you use the incorrect theme, for example in the django-tinymce that I just downloaded, there are only 2 themes "mobile" and "silver", there is no 'modern' theme anymore.
for example: If you change the 'theme': 'silver' in settings.py will work.